# Convert resultset from mysql to a dataframe causing delay

Tags: r, dataframe, fetch, rmysql

Using RMySql library in R, My code builds connection with MySql. Executes SQL query. Pulls records in a resultset and than converts resultset to dataframe. This conversion of result set to dataframe is taking 12 secs.

Is there any alternative in R to do this operation ?

I have tried the following methods:

```
fetch()
dbfetch()
```

both take 12 secs.

Following is the code that I am trying.

```
con <-  dbConnect(MySQL(),user=user, password=pw,dbname=db,host=host, port=3306)
s <- paste0("select * from ", tableName)
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, s)
df <-  dbFetch(rs, n = -1)
```